# Loop two variables one is conditional on another one

Tags: r, loops, conditional-statements

I want to make a loop which contains two variables `i,j`. for each i equals 1:24, j can be 1:24
but I don't know to make this loop;

```
i=1
while(i<=24)
{
   j=seq(1,24,by=1)

   for (j in j)
   {
      cor[i,j]
   }
}
i=i+1
```

is this right? my output is `cor[i,j]`.

Comment: the syntax you're using is not quite right. Can you explain a bit about what it is you are trying to do? Are you trying to compute the `cor`relation between two variables? What does your data look like?

Comment: cor is the matrix output. What I want to do is for each i, like i=1, j takes the values from 1:24 so that the matrix cor can be taken like cor[1,1],cor[1,2],cor[1,3]..............

Comment: Still unclear whether you want to compute some statistic for a combination of variables, or if you just want to end up with a 576 row x 2 column matrix containing all combination of 1:24? If the latter, `cor <- cbind(rep(1:24, each = 24), 1:24)` will do what you want. If that's not what you want - please try editing your question to make it clear what it is you are trying to do. Is `cor` supposed to be the name of the `cor()` function? Or is the some arbitrary name you want to name an object? Note that `[` is used for indexing, not to call the function `cor()`.

Answer (score 2):

In order to accomplish your final goal try...

```
cor(myMatrix)
```

The result is a matrix containing all of the correlations of all of the columns in myMatrix.

If you want to try to go about it the way you were it's probably best to generate a matrix of all of the possible combinations of your items using `combn`.  Try combn(1:4,2) and see what it looks like for a small example.  For your example with 24 columns the best way to cycle through all combinations using a for loop is...

```
myMatrix <- matrix(rnorm(240), ncol = 24)
myIndex <- combn(1:24,2)
for(i in ncol(myIndex)){
    temp <- cor(myMatrix[,myIndex[1,i]],myMatrix[,myIndex[2,i]])
    print(c(myIndex[,i],temp))
}
```

So, it's possible to do it with a `for` loop in R you'd never do it that way.

(and this whole answer is based on a wild guess about what you're actually trying to accomplish because the question, and your comments, are very hard to figure out)